# send get request one after another in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to send request to trigger php code behind following url
`"link.com/carbon/?code=" + code`
Response of this url is not important. 200 is enough.

After it's OK response, I need to get actual data

`"link.com/shorturl.php?short&code=" + code`
and save the response to a variable,

Example response:

```
=> first request < ii
<= 200 OK
=> Second request < ii
<= 200 OK - Content: 6
```

i tried fetch, but second request and first request sent same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to await it as text:

```js
const resultValue = await fetch(`https://flower.nyaizhel.ml/fun/carbon/shorturl.php?short&code=${code}`).then(res => res.text());
// (if code === ii, resultValue = "6")
let resultAsInt = parseInt(resultValue);
```

Comment: output: https://flower.nyaizhel.ml/fun/carbon/shorturl.php?show&id=NaN **and the code:** https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sudo-do/3lc4n/main/index.js?token=APDV6Q2W5XYWLHXERDHADETANXQLC

Comment: await throwed async error btw, i put async some places didn't work.

Comment: The links you sent me all give errors. You need to make sure it is an async function.